# If $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $n+k|n^2$ then $k>\sqrt{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

This is what I tried, can someone please see if this is adequate and if not, provide how to do it?

Suppose that $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ with $n+k|n^2$.
Suppose for contradiction that $k\leq\sqrt{n}$.

By definition, $n^2 = m(n+k)$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}.$
Then $k = \frac{n^2-mn}{m}$.
By assumption that $k\leq \sqrt{n}$, we have

$$\frac{n^2-mn}{m}\leq\sqrt{n}\\ \frac{n^2(n-m)^2}{m^2}\leq n \\ n^3 - 2mn^2 + m^2n - m^2\leq 0$$
which is a contradiction since the LHS goes to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.
Hence, $k>\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: $n$ and $m$ are fixed quantites. You cannot let them go to infinity to obtain the desired conclusion.

Comment: See, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509155/division-in-1-variable/2509165#2509165

Comment: Um, that last step is mysterious. Why can you let $n\to\infty$, and then apply it to a specific $n$? Doesn't $k$ depend on $n$? And hence $m$ depends on $n,k$? So letting $n\to\infty$ doesn't show you anything.

Comment: Is there another way to arrive at a contradiction then or is my initial approach incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n^2=(n-k+t)(n+k)$ for some positive integer $t$.  Then, we have $(n+k)t=k^2$.  As $k\geq 1$ and $t\geq 1$, we have
$$k^2 \geq (n+1)\cdot 1>n\,.$$

**P.S.:**  The motivation for the definition of $t$ is as follows: I thought of the identity $$n^2-k^2=(n-k)(n+k)\,.$$  If $n^2$ (which is greater than $n^2-k^2$) is divisible by $n+k$, then the quotient $\frac{n^2}{n+k}$ must be an integer greater than $n-k$.

> In fact, we have stronger bounds: $$\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{4}}\leq k \leq n^2-n\,.$$ The left inequality becomes an equality if and only if $n=k^2-k$ and $t=1$, whereas the right inequality becomes an equality if and only if $k=n^2-n$ and $t=(n-1)^2$.

Comment: How did you think of that first factor? Why can it not be (n+k-t) instead?

Comment: See the edit for clarification.

Comment: (+1) I see that my estimate is the same. If you think the derivations are too close, I will remove my answer.

Comment: Thank you. About your motivation: could this have been done like this then?  
$$n+k|(n^2-k^2)$$  
since $n+k | n^2$, then $$n+k | k^2.$$  
Then $k^2 = \ell (n+k) \geq n+k > n \implies k > \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Sure, it can.  Note that $\ell$ is just $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n^2=(n-m)(n+k)$, then $(k-m)n=km$. We then have $m\le k-1$, and therefore,
$$
\frac1{k-1}\le\frac1m=\frac1k+\frac1n\tag1
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $nk(k-1)$
$$
kn\le(k+n)(k-1)\iff k^2-k-n\ge0\tag2
$$
Since $k\ge0$, we get
$$
k\ge\frac12+\sqrt{n+\frac14}\tag3
$$

---

I just noticed that directly from $(2)$, we get
$$
k^2\ge n+k\gt n\implies k\gt\sqrt{n}\tag4
$$
without having to solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: This is the same lower estimate for $k$ that Batominovski got, but I didn't see that until hovering over that answer. This explanation is a bit different, so I will leave it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. From your hipotesis $km = n(n-m)$. Due to $k,n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ then $n-m \geq 1$. Now $n^2 \geq n$ and $(n-m)^{2} \geq m^2$ therefore

$k^2m^2 = n^2(n-m)^2 \geq nm^2$ i.e. $km \geq \sqrt{n}m$. This implies $km-\sqrt{n}m\geq 0$ or $m(k-\sqrt{n})\geq 0$ i.e. $k\geq \sqrt{n}$

Comment: Thanks, how did you think of doing this? Just pure algebraic manipulations?

Comment: Why does this hold: $(n-m)^2\geq m^2$?

Comment: I apply the definition of divisibility, and the property of closure for the operations in the integers. I think the important thing is to note that n-m is greater than 1.

Comment: Then, how does it follows from $n-m\geq 1$ that $n^2(n-m)^2\geq nm^2$?

Comment: $n^2 > n$ and if $n-m>1$ then $n^2-2mn \geq 0$ due to $(n-m)^2 \geq 0$

Comment: $(n-m)^2>0$ does not imply $n^2-2nm\geq0$.  You need to show that $n\geq2m$ for that matter.

Comment: With the lack of your response, I am providing a counterexample. We can take $n=6$ and $k=3$, so that $m=4$.  We have $n^2-2nm=36-48=-12<0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot batominovsky. I hadn't have chance to answer before. Yes, you are right and I see my trying of solution is wrong. Regards.